# Does `hash -p` change the pathname of a external command name?

Tags: bash

In my `~.profile`

```
PATH="/path/1/":"/path/2/":"$PATH"
```

`/path/1/` and `/path/2/` both have executable files of the same name `myexecutable`.

In a nonlogin interactive shell, I would like to temporarily exchange the search order between the two directories.

Bash manual says for `hash`

> The -p
>   option inhibits the path search, and filename is used as the location of name.

My way is

```
$ hash -p /path/2/myexecutable
hits    command
   3    /usr/bin/which
   4    /usr/bin/psql
   1    /bin/cat
  10    /usr/bin/sudo
   1    /bin/mv
   1    /usr/bin/whereis
   3    /bin/mkdir
  19    /bin/ls
```

the output is the same as `hash`, and it doesn't seem to change `myexecutable` to be `/path/2/myexecutable`:

```
$ which myexecutable
/path/1/myexecutable
```

So what does `hash -p` do actually?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help hash`:

> hash: hash [-lr] [-p pathname] [-dt] [name ...]
>
> -p pathname       use PATHNAME as the full pathname of NAME

So:

```
$ hash -p   /path/2/myexecutable   myexecutable
```

Will do what you want.

Of course, you can play some games with executable names:

```
$ hash -p   /bin/echo  myexecutable
```

Will run `echo` whenever you call `myexecutable`.

```
$ myexecutable Hello World
Hello World
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it correct that `where myexecutale` doesn't change after `hash -p   /path/2/myexecutable   myexecutable`? I found so, but why is it ?

Comment: Where is not a bash command. How could an external command be aware of bash internal (hash) data structures ?. You may be confused. @Tim

Answer (score 2):

```
$ touch file
$ ls
file
$ hash
hits    command
   1    /usr/bin/touch
   1    /bin/ls
$ hash -p /hello/world/ls ls
$ ls
bash: /hello/world/ls: No such file or directory
```

`hash -p somepath somecommand` sets the hashed path for `somecommand` to the given path `somepath` in `bash`.

This will generally not help you in reversing the `PATH` search order between two directories as you would have to use `hash -p` on all binaries that occur in both directories.  If you only have one such binary, it may be a viable option.
A more portable solution would be to simply prepend the value of `PATH` with the second directory.

If your original `PATH` is

```
/path/1:/path/2:...
```

you first turn it into

```
/path/2:/path/1:/path/2:...
```

then use `hash -r` to reset the hashed paths, and use the binaries as usual.  These will now be picked up from `/path/2` rather than from `/path/1`.

If you save the original `PATH` in a temporary variable, it's easy to restore.

Summary:

```
oldpath=$PATH
PATH=/path/2:$PATH
hash -r

# do stuff

PATH=$oldpath
hash -r
```